# What is the time complexity of this conditionally recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity

This problem comes from https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber-iii. Basically, you have to maximize the amount of money the robber can take without robbing 2 houses in a row.

This is my solution to the problem - it is just DFS, but I am not sure about it's time complexity since there is conditional recursion. Sometimes the child nodes are visited once (when `robbed_previous == true`), otherwise the both child nodes will be visited twice (`robbed_previous == false)`. Was hoping someone could help me understand the time complexity of it.

My solution is with this code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int rob(TreeNode* root) {
        TreeNode sentinel(0, root, nullptr);
        return dfs(sentinel.left, false);
    }
    
    int dfs(TreeNode* root, bool robbed_previous) {
        if (!root) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (robbed_previous) {
            int a = dfs(root->left, false); // skipped this house
            int b = dfs(root->right, false); // skipped this house
            return a + b;
        } else {
            int a = dfs(root->left, true); // robbed this house
            int b = dfs(root->right, true); // robbed this house
            int c = dfs(root->left, false); // skipped this house
            int d = dfs(root->right, false); // skipped this house
            return max(a + b + root->val, c + d);
        }
    }
};
```

My thought is that it is `O(0.5*2^N)` where N = number of nodes because in the worst case, every other node will be "robbed" which visits the left and right child twice each.

Comment: I guess DFS complexity is `O(V + E)`,

Comment: The complexity being exponential should be sufficient to allow you to tell that the solution is unacceptable. It should be pretty straight-forward to reduce the complexity to `O(N)` simply by saving intermediate results for the subtrees: For each subtree save the optimum results for robbing and not robbing the root; you can determine this in `O(1)` given the results for the subtrees.

Comment: @fabian I know how to memoize, I just want to know the time complexity of this non-memoized solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to approach this. But let's consider the following things:

- Your algorithm basically tries all the possible valid permutations of robbed and skipped houses.
- You always descend all the way to the bottom of the tree, so the complexity of each permutation is O(N).

The question is then how many permutations there are. This is likely in the order of O(2^N), so the total complexity would be O(N * 2^N).

As fabian mentioned, this approach is very slow, instead you should be able to memoize the results for an invocation of `dfs()` and avoid revisiting the tree unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: It would be 2^H if you would make the same choice of skipping/robbing for all nodes at a given height. But since you can choose independently among nodes at the same height (if the parent wasn't already robbed of course), I assume it's in the order of 2^N. I might be wrong though.